# Incorrect identity

Tags: trigonometry

I recently ran into the identity below and no matter what I do I cannot make my LHS = RHS, is this identity incorrect or is my maths just not up to scratch,

$ (1 + cosx)cosecx + \frac{1}{cosec(1+cotx)} = 2cosecx$

Please help me prove this true or false it's bugging me,

Comment: This is false. The second term should be reciprocal of first term.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was